# LAN to LAN VPN vs VPN Token

Tags: vpn, local-area-network

We're looking to set up connectivity between our local server and a remote server.  We have the 2 following options for accessing the remote server.

1. LAN to LAN VPN
2. VPN Token

What is the difference, and is one method recommended over the other?  All servers are running Linux.

Answer (score 0):

With [openVPN](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html) you can build a LAN to LAN connection between 2 servers or gateways with certificates.

[LAN to LAN turorial](http://www.shorewall.net/OPENVPN.html)